# A singularity of hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions

Do generalized hypergeometric functions 
$${}_p F_q(a_1,\ldots,a_p; b_1, \ldots,b_q; z) $$
with $p = q+1$ always possess a singularity at $z=1$, independent of the their parameters $a_1,\ldots,a_p$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_q$ under the provision that all cases of finite polynomials are excluded? Can someone mention a reliable source for such a statement or provide a counterexample?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close because this thread does not need to keep being bumped by the bot.

Comment: Why "does not need"? Apparently my answer was not sufficiently useful to OP, and thus deserves a better answer...

Answer (score 2):

For the $p=q+1$ case, taking the branch cut from 1 to ∞ is conventional so that you can speak of the *principal branch* of ${}_{q+1} F_q$ ; the function is multivalued outside the unit disk, and 1 and ∞ are branch points.

For unit argument, the key word "Saalschützian" is what you might take into account; see [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-114-01/S0002-9939-1992-1068116-2/S0002-9939-1992-1068116-2.pdf) by Bühring for more information.